# Why do cats' claws retract?

Tags: zoology, physiology, mammals

Humans have nails, horses have hooves - but they are always exposed. Why are cats' claws retractable rather than always exposed? Is it related to "[Why are there nail growth differences  between humans and other mammals?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/329/why-are-there-nail-growth-differences-between-humans-and-other-mammals/330#330)"?

Comment: Just a speculation, but cats' claws are a lot sharper than the other examples you gave, and are more likely to get caught on things(particularly when a cat is stalking prey), dulled by the environment, or cause self-injury. The purposes and uses of hooves, in particular, are quite different. When would it ever be beneficial for a horse to retract its hooves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retraction of claws is a feature of the cat family, [Felidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felidae) along with some [civets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civet) that helps them keep those sharp by preventing unwanted wear.These claws are important for the members of cat family, including domestic cats that hunt preys by grasp attack rather than bite.

However cheetah among the big cats that usually hunt through bite-attack, has evolved to have semi-retractable claws that help it generate [traction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traction_(engineering)).

In pet cats it has offered another advantage:
Retraction keeps them from getting tangled in fabrics.

Sources:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claw)
- Russell AP, Bryant HN. 2001. Claw retraction and protraction in Carnivora: the cheetah (Acinonyx jubatus)
  as an atypical felid. J Zool ,Lond 254:67-76.

Comment: A [footage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnE0NqrnDCU) of cat hunting.

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding the reason cats claws are retractable due to the tendons in the cats paw http://kids.britannica.com/comptons/art-53056/All-cats-except-the-cheetah-have-retractable-claws